# Rotating 2 motors using PIC16F84A, ULN2003A driver, and assembly language when all 3 buttons are pressed?

Tags: assembly

How to select the R3 button in assembly language
i cant provide the schematic capture
this is the parts:
device: PIC16F84A, ULN2003A driver
3 resistor
3 buttons
4 power
3 grounds
2 motors

i want the output if i pressed all the three button the two motor will rotate
heres my program

```
program MyProjectExer1

' Declarations section 

main:
'   Main program
trisb=%00000000
 trisa=%11111
 portb=%00000000
 do
 if (porta.0 = 0 ) and (porta.1 = 0) then
 portb = %00000001
 delay_ms (500)
 end if
 if (porta.0 = 0 ) and (porta.1 = 0) then
 portb = %00000001
 delay_ms (500)
 end if
 if (porta.0 = 1 ) and (porta.1 = 0) then
 portb = %00000010
 delay_ms (500)
 end if
 if (porta.0 = 1 ) and (porta.1 = 1) then
 portb = %00000000
 delay_ms (500)
 end if
 loop until false
end.
```

Comment: Are you using MicroBasic?